# merging two list of lists based on ele

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, list-comparison

I am new to python and need some help:
I have the following lists of lists

```
FirstList = [[joe, 12-mar, 2101],[mike, 13-mar, 2102],[mario, 15-mar, 2103]]
SecondList = [[2524, joe],[2786, mike]]
```

I would like to compare these two nested lists by name with the following:

If the name from the second list exists in the first list, the output should be:

`[[joe, 12-mar, 2101, 2524],[mike, 13-mar, 2102, 2786]]`

If it is not inside, it should be skipped.

many thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried by yourself and why it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lists always follow the format you provided, you could do this:

```py
FirstList = [['joe', '12-mar', 2101],['mike', '13-mar', 2102],['mario', '15-mar', 2103]]
SecondList = [[2524, 'joe'],[2786, 'mike']]

namesMap = {entry[0]: i for i, entry in enumerate(FirstList)}

mergedList = [
        [
            entry[1], 
            FirstList[namesMap[entry[1]]][1],
            FirstList[namesMap[entry[1]]][2],
            entry[0]
        ]
        for entry in SecondList if entry[1] in namesMap
    ]

print(mergedList) # [['joe', '12-mar', 2101, 2524], ['mike', '13-mar', 2102, 2786]]
```